# Use multiple index on seek method VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, indexing, seek

How to use multiple index key with equal on first field and greather than on second field.

ex:

on MS Access

```
Table: Persons(Name[string], Family_name, Age[Int])
Index: Second_key(Name, Age)
```

on VBA

```
DIM Name as string
DIM Age as Integer
DIM Table_1 as Recordset

Name = "Tom"
Age = 20

Set Table_1 = Currentdb.OpenRecorset("Persons")
Table_1.INDEX = "Second_key"
Table_1.SEEK "=", Name, ">", Age
```

and I get error "RUN-TIME error '3421' Type conversion error"

MS Access allows searching by multiple keys, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221096%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Please, help Me.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring your example a bit, because it makes no sense to me why you'd use that specific index for that sort of data, not even mentioning why you'd want to seek through it that way. I'm just assuming that some part of this is an abstract example you worked up just to ask the general question...

Double check the documentation. `Recordset.Seek` doesn't expect you to use different comparators for each column in a multicolumn index. Instead, it will find the first item that matches for the comparator and all values specified. You'd want to replace your current code with something like `Table_1.SEEK ">=", Name, Age` which will seek to the first row where Name >= `Name` and Age >= `Age`

But that's probably not quite what you wanted to achieve, because it allows Name > `Name` and Age = `Age`. So you're probably better off just changing to a SQL query that gives exactly what you wanted, like

```
SELECT TOP 1 Name, Family_Name, Age
FROM Persons
WHERE Name = [SearchName]
  AND Age > [SearchAge]
```

then use a `QueryDef` to get a recordset from this saved, parameterized query like in these examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

In a real base I need search first service intervention after a specific date in the indicated machine.
And I use query

    `select min(date) 
    from Table_01
    where ATM_SN = 'A1230' and date >#8-16-2016# and region = 'WARSAW';`
but, this works very slowly...

I wanted to use the seek methods with various comparisons to accelerate the program performance,
Well, I can't.

Comment: @MirekF.: To speed up your query, make sure that all columns in the WHERE clause are indexed.